# How to wait ProgressDialog before dismiss in onPause activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an activity that loads the AsyncTask within `onCreate`, however, I'm getting an exception   because the activity already finished the life cycle but the ProgressDialog is still running.

My solution was :

Call the dismiss method within `onDestroy` and `onPause` method. The problem here was, the `ProgressDialog` is now useless, it got dismissed even the background task wasn't even done pulling the data.

Also tried this in `onPause`, but the infinite loop doesn't terminate.

```
    while(progress.isShowing()){

    }
    progress.dismiss();
```

Comment: If your task is outliving your `Activity` then you should consider using a `Service`

Comment: As codeMagic says - use a `Service` and also use a `Notification` to display progress.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get the event from aynctask's onpostexecute method and dismiss it. Make an interface to get the event and pass it to asynctask constructor. OnPPostExecute method of asyntask, call the method of that interface and dismiss the progress bar there.